# How can I capture the output of a shell script invoked from Ruby?

Tags: ruby, bash, stdout

I am catching emails to "script@localhost" with /etc/aliases:

```
script:   root,"|/path-to-my-script"
```

this gets an email on STDIN and I am parsing and passing it to other scripts.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
email = ARGF.read
...parse...parse-some-more...
system("/my-other-script.sh #{email.todo}")
```

What would be a best way to capture the STDOUT of `my-other-script.sh` for troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going with :

```
out = `/my-other-script.sh #{email.todo} 2>&1`
log.debug $?.exitstatus
log.debug out
```

seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at `IO.popen` yet?

I'm not an expert, but it might be worth taking a look there.